# Obtener filas donde una fecha dada esté entre dos fechas del modelo ya existentes

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta en Django donde, yo le doy una fecha '2022-07-11' y necesito que me de las filas que estén entre 2 fechas que ya existen en el modelo vigencia_inicio, vigencia_fin pero no logró crear la consulta.
Estoy intentando hacer algo como esto:

```
class Planes(models.Model):
  vigencia_inicio = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  vigencia_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

fecha_dada = '2022-07-11'

res = Planes.objects.raw('select * from Planes where to_date(fecha_dada, "DD/MM/YYYY") between to_date(vigencia_inicio,"DD/MM/YYYY") and to_date(vigencia_fin, "DD/MM/YYYY")')
```

El punto es que me tiene que regresar las filas donde la fecha que el usuario ponga se encuentre entre la vigencia_incio y la vigencia_fin.

Answer (score 0):

Si te estoy entendiendo bien, esto debería funcionarte:

```
Planes.objects.filter(
    vigencia_inicio__lte=fecha_dada,
    vigencia_fin__gte=fecha_dada)
```

Básicamente lo que haces con este filtro es obtener todos los planes cuya vigencia de inicio sea menor o igual que la fecha que le has dado (LTE = less than or equal), y que la vigencia de fin sea mayor o igual que la fecha que le has dado (GTE = greater than or equal).